# CSS3 :after disappear if his parent has overflow:hidden;

Tags: css, overflow, pseudo-element

I've the following problem:
I'm trying to show an arrow, and it works if I remove the overflow:hidden from #colorSelect. But I need overflow:hidden 'cos I have flow elements inside.

How can I fix this? How can I show the arrow (:after element) and keeping the overflow in the same time?
Thank you.

```css
#colorSelect {
width: 70%;
background: #3B3A3A;
border-radius: 5px;
clear: both;
margin: 30px auto 0;
padding: 20px;
position: relative;
color: #fff;
font-size: .8em;
overflow: hidden;
border: 1px solid rgba(150,150,150,0.00);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 22px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.50); 
/*display:none;*/
}

#colorSelect:after {
bottom: 100%;
left: 50%;
border: solid transparent;
content: " ";
height: 0;
width: 0;
position: absolute;
pointer-events: none;
border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
border-bottom-color: #3B3A3A;
border-width: 10px;
margin-left: -10px;       
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Use `:before` to show the arrow, and `:after` to clear the Float just like follows

```css
#colorSelect {
width: 70%;
background: #3B3A3A;
border-radius: 5px;
clear: both;
margin: 30px auto 0;
padding: 20px;
position: relative;
color: #fff;
font-size: .8em;
border: 1px solid rgba(150,150,150,0.00);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 22px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.50); 
/*display:none;*/
}

#colorSelect:before {
bottom: 100%;
left: 50%;
border: solid transparent;
content: " ";
height: 0;
width: 0;
position: absolute;
pointer-events: none;
border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
border-bottom-color: #3B3A3A;
border-width: 10px;
margin-left: -10px;       
}

#colorSelect:after{
    content:"";
    display:block;
    clear:both;
}
```

Comment: Thank you su much! You helped me a lot!

Comment: @DrwMay You are welcome mate!, if you find my answer useful you can upvote and accept it